# jasmine testing service angular - could not find an object to spy upon for getBaseUrl()

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am new to jasmine unit test service in angular, trying to achieve unit test service which has simple get method with `Observable` as a return, for which I am getting the URL from another file, in this `ApiEndpointsConfig` but for some reason, I couldn't find the `getBaseUrl()`, any help is much appreciated. here is the link for [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-simple-http-client-test-ntkwgi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the url used in the service is different from the url that is used in the expectOne. To counteract this error, you can do the following. Change the url in api-endpoints.config to be.

```
 public get getBaseUrl(){
    return 'http://example.com/app/data';
  }
```

And then change the url in the expectOne to be as the following:-

```
const req = httpMock.expectOne(spy() + '/app/data');
```

Only then you will have matching urls and the expectOne would succeed.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to add :

```
apiEndpoints = TestBed.get(ApiEndpointsConfig);
```

to your beforeEach in test.service.spec.ts

This will solve your problem. But you'll get another error linked to the test itself;)
If you can't handle another one, give me a call

Comment: I added the above line already but I dint saved the stackblitz, anyway, like you said facing with match URL error this time, I tried to create a spy on getter method, I still see 'Match URL, found none' error, let me know if you have any ideas on this, thank you!